# view more and view less with useState hook in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  fresh to react and useState hooks (still learning). I want to create show more/less button with use of an Array of images and React hooks. I import the images into div, I wanted to set button on the last and the show the images on the click of button.

I am getting the error:

> text.slice is not function

The thing is, the code is written with use of function component.

here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import '../assets/css/Product.css';

const ReadMore = ({ children }) => {
    const text = children;
    const [isReadMore, setIsReadMore] = useState(true);
    const toggleReadMore = () => {
        setIsReadMore(!isReadMore);
    };
    return (
        <p className='text'>
            {isReadMore ? text.slice(0, 150) : text}
            <span onClick={toggleReadMore} className='read-or-hide'>
                {isReadMore ? '...read more' : ' show less'}
            </span>
        </p>
    );
};

export const Product = () => {
    const card_image = [
        {
            image: 'CLT_Food_BeverageBar.jpg',
            title: 'Charlotte',
            subtitle: '(CLT)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'Centurion_Cropped_0001_Bar.jpg',
            title: 'Dallas',
            subtitle: '(DFW)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'DEN_GameRoom-LR_1200x540.jpg',
            title: 'Denver',
            subtitle: '(DEN)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'IAH_Bar&Buffet_1200x600.jpg',
            title: 'Houston',
            subtitle: '(IAH)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'amxtcl_Lounge_01_cmyk_1200x600.jpg',
            title: 'Las Vegas',
            subtitle: '(LAS)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'LAX_hero.jpg',
            title: 'Los Angeles',
            subtitle: '(LAX)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'LoungeAreaTalent1200x600.jpg',
            title: 'Miami',
            subtitle: '(MIA)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
        {
            image: 'JFK_Carousel_3.jpg',
            title: 'New York',
            subtitle: '(JFX)',
            button: 'Explore Lounge',
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container'>
                <ReadMore>
                    <div className='row introduction'>
                        {card_image.map((card) => (
                            <div className='col-lg-3 pt-5'>
                                <div
                                    className='location_card'
                                    style={{
                                        backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.REACT_APP_ASSET_URL}/card_image/${card.image})`,
                                        objectFit: 'cover',
                                    }}>
                                    <div className='location-overly'>
                                        <h3 className='h2'>
                                            {card.title}
                                            <br />
                                            {card.subtitle}
                                        </h3>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            class='btn_product '>
                                            {card.button}
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </ReadMore>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please format your code! using \```YOUR CODE GOES HERE ```

Comment: `text.slice is not function` because your text is not a string if you hard code `text = "Some Text"` will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use conditional rendering, this means that when a state changes, your UI also changes. Sorry, I don't think I explained it that well, so here's some example code.

```js
import * from x "xyz xyz";

const App = () => {
   const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
   
   if(showMore){
      return(
          <MoreStuff/>
       );
   }

   return(
      <DefaultStuff/>
    );
}
```

Resources:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_conditional_rendering.asp

https://zh-hans.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const allCars = [
  { name: 'Audi', country: 'Germany' },
  { name: 'BMW', country: 'Germany' },
  { name: 'Chevrolet', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'Citroen', country: 'France' },
  { name: 'Hyundai', country: 'South Korea' },
  { name: 'Mercedes-Benz', country: 'Germany' },
  { name: 'Renault', country: 'France' },
  { name: 'Seat', country: 'Spain' },
];

function CarFilter() {
  const [showMoreData, setShowMoreData] = useState(3);
  const showMore = () => {
    if (showMoreData === 3) {
      setShowMoreData(allCars.length);
    } else if (showMoreData > 3) {
      setShowMoreData(3);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ul>
        {allCars.slice(0, showMoreData).map((car, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            {car.name} - {car.country}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {allCars.length > 3 && (
        <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
          {showMoreData > 3 ? 'Show More ' : 'Show less'}
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CarFilter;
```